# Scaling UV map to bounds but preserve mesh proportions

Tags: uv

I am doing *Project from view with scaling to bounds*, but it doesn't take proportions into account. There is a checkbox about correct aspect ratio, but it is useless.

Is there a way to do it quickly, without messing in UV editor with enabled snapping to pixels, to prevent unnecessary stretch when scailing to bounds.

[image]

Comment: Project from view>Bounds will take the proportions from the image used in for the UV mapping, not from the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Example with an oval shape :)    :

1: **UV Mapping**  >  **Project from View**.

2: In the **UV Editor** open the **UV's** menu and choose **Pack Islands**, turn off the **Rotate** option.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is nice cheating! Let's make thing more interesting - put three ovals in a row (X axis) and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you need to have the Orthographic option enabled.

[image]

Comment: It works only with this rectangular mesh. But try for example oval. With enabled clipping, part of it will be sticked to UV-space border and rounded shape will be ruined.